# Bash syntax error if condition

Tags: bash

I‘m trying to figure out why this simple code produces a syntax error. Any advice?

```
./g.sh: line 4: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
./g.sh: line 4: syntax error near `;'
./g.sh: line 4: `    if [[ "$y" == "rsa" ]]; then'
```

Here‘s the code:

```
for x in *; do
  for y in rsa ed25519; do
    yb=''
    if [[ "$y" == "rsa" ]]; then
      yb=' -b 4096'
    fi
    echo "x: ${x} y: ${y} yb: ${yb}"
  done
done
```

It‘s just test code that will be used in generating rsa/ed25519 keys automatically for many machines.

Some additional infos:

- Ubuntu Server 17.10
- GNU bash 4.4.12

Comment: Are you really using bash? Try with bash yourfile.sh

Comment: @fernand0 yes, the file has the bash shebang and I‘ve checked /bin/bash already. Running it directly with „bash g.sh“ produces the same syntax error.

Comment: I've tried with my own computer and I cannot reproduce the problem. This is the reason for my question @Spartan-117

Comment: @fernand0 I can‘t reproduce it on my macbook either. But it surely is using bash. Very weird, thanks for trying it!

Comment: Maybe your bash is not really a bash shell? Can you check if it is a symbolik link to another shell?

Comment: Did you type the code in your question, or copy-and-paste it from your script? The code shown here is absolutely fine.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` to log each command as it's run. With a new enough version of bash (which 4.4 certainly is), this will make nonprintable characters visible.

Comment: BTW, you should never use a string variable to hold command-line arguments. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- if your code were being written in line with best practices (and assuming you're actually going to be passing `yb` on a command line), that variable should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

> > nano 2.sh

```
for x in *; do
 for y in rsa ed25519; do
 yb=''
  if [[ "$y" == "rsa" ]]; then
   yb=' -b 4096'
  fi
 echo "x: ${x} y: ${y} yb: ${yb}"
 done
done}
```

> > chmod +x 2.sh
> >
> > /2.sh

```
x: 1.sh y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: 1.sh y: ed25519 yb: 
x: 2.sh y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: 2.sh y: ed25519 yb: 
x: abc.txt y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: abc.txt y: ed25519 yb: 
x: dene.csv y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: dene.csv y: ed25519 yb: 
x: deneme y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: deneme y: ed25519 yb: 
x: dene.sh y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: dene.sh y: ed25519 yb: 
x: dene.txt y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: dene.txt y: ed25519 yb: 
x: Desktop y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: Desktop y: ed25519 yb: 
x: Downloads y: rsa yb:  -b 4096
x: Downloads y: ed25519 yb:
```

GNU bash, version 4.4.12

Parrot 4.11.6-1parrot6`enter code here`